# How to change the branch with significant deviations?

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm creating a new website in a new git-branch. Because there are many changes in the libraries used and the content, there are strong variations (new, deleted, renamed) in the existing files and folders.

If I change the branch now (Team -> Switch To -> The other branch - right?), only the contents of the files/folders, that are present in both projects will be changed. New folders and files are partially missing, while deleted ones are suddenly back. There is chaos, but not in the remote repositories. If I delete the project and reimport the branch, everything is right. But it always takes a long time.

How can I make sure that all folders and files in the workspace are synchronized after changing branches?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look to the `git worktree` feature that will suit you better!

Comment: @Philippe Is this directly supported by Eclipse?

Comment: I don't know Eclipse. But that's really easy to do with command line. Just have to know the one time `git worktree add` command line to create the worktree and that's all.